# Setting up secure email on Thunderbird

Tags: encryption, thunderbird, certificate, digital-signature

I'm trying to set Thunderbird up to send/receive encrypted emails. Here is a screenshot from the screen where you can select certificates:

[image]

However, it doesn't really explain the difference between the "*Digital Signing*" cert and the "*Encryption*" cert:

- Isn't digital signing the same as encrypting data?
- What types of cert files (PEM? PKX?) are accepted here?

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't digital signing the same as encrypting data?

No, it's not.

A digital signature is appended to an E-Mail message by you, using your own private key thus **authenticating** the message (proving that the sender is actually you).

Encryption is applied by the sender of a message sent to you. The sender uses your public key (contained in the certificate), only you (not even the sender) can later decrypt the message using your private key. This ensures the **confidentiality** of the message.

To sum it up, under *Digital Signing* you need to setup a certificate you want to use to sign your outgoing messages, while the certiciate configured under **Encryption** is used to decrypt your incoming messages.
Those certificates are usually the same, but they do not have to.

> What types of cert files (PEM? PKX?) are accepted here?

Since for both operations, signing and decrypting, you also need your private key, a plain certificate (as stored in a .pem or .cer file) is not enough. You need a container which stores your keypair along with the certifcate, this is usually in the PKCS#12 format. Its file ending is usually .p12 or .pfx